# PhantomJS: setTimeout Still Not Working?

Tags: phantomjs, browser-automation, headless-browser

There are a lot of posts on the net [documenting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/dEI28sMwGEU) a serious bug in PhantomJS, in which the delay in setTimeout is ignored. Most of them are a few years old. I would have thought this bug had been fixed by now, but I appear to be encountering it:

Here's my PhantomJS test code, used with PhantomJS v2.1.1:

```
page.open(uri, function (status) {
    var content = page.content;
    console.log('page loaded');

    if (status !== "success")
    {
        phantomResult = JSON.stringify({
          "status": status,
          "content": "page not opened"
        });
        console.log(phantomResult);
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        content = page.content;
        page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) { console.log(msg); };

        console.log('about to try timeout test');
        window.setTimeout(console.log('set timeout test'), 100);

        console.log('about to try timeout test 2');
        window.setTimeout(console.log('set timeout test 2'), 2000);

        console.log('about to try timeout test 3');
        window.setTimeout(console.log('set timeout test 3'), 4000);

        window.setTimeout(console.log(phantom.exit(1)), 6000);
    }
});
```

The console.log calls executed via setTimeout are executed immediately one right after the other, with no delay between them.

Has this bug not been fixed yet? I'm using OS X and calling phantomJS via the terminal.

Hopefully there's a fix for this! Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Comment: Probably irrelevant after 6 years, but your problem is that you don't pass a function to setTimeout, but the result of the call to console.log, which is then immediately executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
window.setTimeout(function () { console.log('set timeout test') }, 100);
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by rolling my own setTimeout code:

```
var waitStart = new Date();
var done = false;
var timeNow;
var interval = 1000;
while (!done) {
    timeNow = new Date();
    done = timeNow - waitStart > interval;
    //console.log('timeNow - waitStart = ' + (timeNow - waitStart));
}
```